# Convertir Lista a Array Multidimencional

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Trabajo con C# tengo la necesidad de convertir una lista a un array multidimencional

Lo que me envían en la lista es lo siguiente

```
int[,] matriz = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 2 }, { 3, 4, 3 }, { 5, 6, 1 } };
```

Pero lo están enviando de la siguiente manera

```
List<List<int>> arr
```

Necesito convertir esa lista a array multidimencional para que quede de la siguiente manera

```
int[,] matriz = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 2 }, { 3, 4, 3 }, { 5, 6, 1 } };
```

¿Como convertir esa lista a Array?

Lo que pasa es que resolví un ejercicio de la manera que es un array multidimencional pero a la hora de implementar el código me doy con la sorpresa que es una lista

```
int sumaDiagonalI = 0;
        int sumaDiaganalD = 0;

        int[,] matriz = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 2 }, { 3, 4, 3 }, { 5, 6, 1 } };

        int cantFilas = matriz.GetLength(0);
        int cantColumnas = matriz.GetLength(1);

        if (cantFilas != cantColumnas)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No es una matriz cuadrada");
            return;
        }

        var indiceMáximo = Math.Min(cantFilas, cantColumnas);
        for (var i = 0; i < indiceMáximo; i++)
        {
            sumaDiagonalI += matriz[i, i];
        }

        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cantFilas; i++)
        {
            j = ((cantFilas - 1) - i);
            sumaDiaganalD += matriz[i, j];
        }
```

En este algoritmo sumo las diagonales de la izquierda y de la derecha

Comment: Cada sublista de la lista principal tiene la misma cantidad de elementos?

Comment: Si es igual .....

Comment: Podrías modificar la pregunta, la parte en donde describes en como recibes la lista "List<List<int>> arr". Si puedes mostrar en una imagen como está dispuesta la lista "arr".
Por el momento intenta con: "(variable lista).ToArray();"

Comment: Ok, sería bueno que pusieras lo que has intentando

Comment: @Japv listo, tocaria resolverlo como lista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes la lista:

```
List<List<int>> list;
```

Donde cada elemento de la lista es a su vez una lista de enteros.

Por tanto las columnas serán la cantidad de elementos que tienen la sublistas de la lista principal, como dices que todas esas sublistas tienen la misma longitud pues puedes usar cualquier sublista de la lista principal para obtener la cantidad de columnas. Por tanto cogemos la primera posición de la lista principal(la primera sublista).

```
int columnas = lista.ElementAt(0).Count();
```

Usamos el **método ElementAt** a la cual se le pasa como parámetro un entero, que indica el índice que ocupa el elemento en la lista. En este caso obtenemos el primer elemento de la lista(índice **0**) y como este primer elemento es una lista también, pues le aplicamos el **método Count** y así obtenemos la cantidad de columnas.

Para obtener las filas hacemos los siguiente:

```
int filas = lista.Count();
```

De esta forma obtenemos la cantidad de elementos que guarda la lista principal, es decir la cantidad de filas.

Después vendría la construcción de la matriz:

```
int[,] matriz = new int[filas, columnas];
```

Y ahora vendría el llenado de la matriz:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lista.Count(); i++)
{
    var subLista = lista.ElementAt(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < subLista.Count(); j++)
    {         
       matriz[i,j] = subLista.ElementAt(j); 
    }
}
```

Hacemos dos **ciclos for** anidados uno para recorrer la lista principal y el otro para recorrer cada sublista de la lista principal. Obtenemos cada subLista de la lista principal y con esta subLista es que vamos llenando la matriz.